# log4net print DateTime/calling class/function on each line

Tags: c#, log4net

Is there any way using log4net to automatically write date/time and class name/function name to the start of each logged line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `log4net` configuration file modify Appender section by adding a PatternLayout with custom format. Following pattern will output *DateTime ClassName.MethodName*

```
 <appender name="DebugOut"
             type="log4net.Appender.OutputDebugStringAppender">
     <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <conversionPattern value="%date{MM/dd/yy HH:mm} %C{1}.%M" />
     </layout>
   </appender>
```

You can output fully qualified name of class by changing `%C{1}` to `%C`